# Send prefix key to tmux session

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux

So I am using this tmux plugin for logging the entire tmux history. https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging

The plugin uses the key bindings `C-b` + `P` to start and stop the logging session. Basically, `prefix` + `P`.

I am programatically trying to to stop and start the logging session to create a new output file for each day. For this, I want to setup a crontab to run a simple script. The content of the script is as follows.

```
tmux send-keys -t 0:0 C-b P # stops the logging session
tmux send-keys -t 0:0 C-b P # restarts the logging session
```

But when I attach to the tmux session, what I see is this printed on the screen.

```
^BP^BP
```

So `C-b` instead of being treated as a `prefix`, is being treated as a normal key combination. I have also tried using the following, but still the same result.

```
tmux send-prefix -t 0:0 # prints ^B on the session window
tmux send-keys -t 0:0 P
```

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the maintainer of tmux](https://github.com/orgs/tmux/people), ["You can't trigger tmux key bindings with send-keys. You could just run the commands the key is bound to instead."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613347/257010).

---

For your specific case, I see [in logging.tmux](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging/blob/master/logging.tmux):

```sh
tmux bind-key "$logging_key" run-shell "$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/toggle_logging.sh"
tmux bind-key "$pane_screen_capture_key" run-shell "$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/screen_capture.sh"
tmux bind-key "$save_complete_history_key" run-shell "$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/save_complete_history.sh"
tmux bind-key "$clear_history_key" run-shell "$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/clear_history.sh"
```

where `$CURRENT_DIR` is the directory that this script lives in.

So, find that script on your machine and then change your send-keys to

```sh
tmux send-keys -t 0:0 '$SCRIPT_DIR/scripts/toggle_logging.sh' Enter
```

Comment: Thanks. Sort of works but still an edge case since someone could already have something running in that tmux window and it would need to be stopped first.

Comment: Sure. I'm sure you could alter the `toggle_logging.sh` script to account for that.

Comment: What about a scenario where you want to copy some content from one pane and paste it to another?  This requires entering into copy mode, copying, pasting in another pane, all of which rely on prefix.